# How to Get and Use File Name from FileInfo

Tags: c#, datetime, fileinfo

So basically what I'm trying to do is get the date modified of a file that FileInfo gets. Hopefully the code will explain a little better.

```
DirectoryInfo prefetch = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\Windows\\Prefetch");
FileInfo[] log = prefetch.GetFiles("2*");
if (log.Length == 0)
    MessageBox.Show("Nothing Found");
else
    DateTime modified = System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTime(Convert.ToString(log));
    MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(modified));
```

The above code does not work/do what I want it do. sSo say in Prefetch there is a file called log2.txt. the FileInfo would detect that it is there, but I'm trying to display the Date Modified of that file. I know how to see if it exists and how to show the date modified, but I can't figure out how to retrieve the name of the file/file that FileInfo finds then display the date modified. Any suggestions or answers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: note that on Windows DateCreated and DateModified are not deterministic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is only one file, I believe it would be `file[0].LastWriteTime`

Comment: So that works, is there a way to show the one that was modified most recently? Like [0] would show first one, but if you didn't know how many there were, and you wanted to get the one thats most recent, can you?

Comment: log.OrderByDesc(x=>x.LastWriteTime).FirstOrDefault()

Answer (score 0):

You can check FileInfo class at [System.IO.FileSystemInfo.FileInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo(v=vs.110).aspx)

To retrieve the file name and modified date you just access to property Name and LastWriteTime

I modified your example code to show the file name of the first element in your log array.

```
DirectoryInfo prefetch = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\Windows\\Prefetch");
FileInfo[] log = prefetch.GetFiles("2*");
if (log.Length == 0)
    MessageBox.Show("Nothing Found");
else
   MessageBox.Show(log[0].Name);
```